# pip install numpy error - Unmatched "

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv

I am trying to install numpy in a python3 virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

After running the above, the installation fails with an error something like this...

```
error Command "gcc ..." failed with exit status 1

Unmatched ".
Unmatched ".
```

Why does this happen and how can I install numpy correctly

Answer (score 0):

When you install numpy using pip, it runs various shell commands to build the parts of numpy that are written in c. Your environment's `$SHELL` variable will be used to determine which shell to use. In this case, `csh` is being used but the command in the installation script expects to be able to use bash like syntax.

## Make sure your `$SHELL` is set to `/bin/bash` before building

The syntax for this depends on your shell

### bash/zsh:

```
export SHELL="/bin/bash"
```

### fish:

```
set -x SHELL "/bin/bash/"
```

### csh:

```
setenv SHELL /bin/bash
```

Now you should be able to run `pip install numpy` again, and it might work this time.

[This is possibly a {bug/oversight} in numpy]